# What would be the arithmetic/algebraic rules for solving the problem $500=\frac{66}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{V^2}{(3 \times10^8)^2}}}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Every direction I take to solve this problem leaves me with a negative on one side of the equation and $V^2$ on the other. Arithmetic/algebraic rules were the cause of my last question on this site, and it is very irritating. I will provide some of my attempt below and if anyone can suggest texts for me to read to improve my understanding of algebraic rules or point me in the right direction, I would be appreciative. I'm pretty sure I understand at least the basic rules! Which is why this is so frustrating to me. Please don't give the answer directly but hint me in the right direction, please and thank you!

Attempt:

I squared both sides of the equation which gave me this:

$$250,000=\frac{4,356}{1-\frac{V^2}{(3\times10^8)^2}}$$

And then from here, I get:

$$250,000-\frac{250,000V²}{(3\times10^8)^2} = 4356$$

From here I realize that I'll be attempting to square a negative which I know isn't possible. Did I mess up at the very first step? If so what is the proper first step? I'm solving for $V^2$ obviously.

Comment: When you say squaring a negative is impossible, do you mean multiplying a negative number by itself - because that is possible. If you have a negative number $-a ,a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, then $-a\times{-a}=+a^2$. I think you might be wanting to say it is not possible to take the square root of a negative number with only expecting a real answer.

Comment: Square root is what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing fine so far.  Now move the $V^2$ term to the other side and subtract $4356$ from each side.  You just need $V$ to be a little less than $3\cdot 10^8$ so the fraction is a little less than $1$.

Added:
$$250,000-\frac{250,000V^2}{(3\times10^8)^2} = 4356\\
250,000-4356=\frac{250,000V^2}{(3\times10^8)^2}\\
(250,000-4356)\frac{(3\cdot 10^8)^2}{250,000}=V^2\\
\sqrt{(250,000-4356)\frac{(3\cdot 10^8)^2}{250,000}}=V$$

Comment: But in order to move V² to the other side I would have to multiply by the denominator first correct? This is what throws me off, the fraction V² belongs to is negative as it's subtracted.

Comment: No, you can add the term as a fraction to both sides.  That moves it to the other side as a positive quantity.  See my addition.  Also, as a MathJax hint, you can get squares with ^2 and they look nicer than the characters you used.

Comment: OMG you are a genius

Comment: I always trip up on these simple things! That's such an obvious solution.